# Defining new split environment with reduced spacing

Tags: equations, environments, amsmath, setspace

this is my first stackexchange question so apologies for any bad etiquette.

I'm writing a document in double spacing.  I don't wants the gaps between the lines of a multi-line equation to be that large, though.

I know that I can make this change globally by using

```
\setlength{\jot}{<size>}
```

...but this also affects other spacings that I don't want to change, e.g. in an xymatrix or when using \gather

I also know that I can keep the changes local by using

```
\begingroup\setlength{\jot}{<size>}\begin{split}
...
\end{split}\endgroup
```

...but there is a very large number of split equations in my document and I'd prefer not to make it even messier by doing this.

I tried to define a new environment to effect this local change, like so

```
\newenvironment{Split}%
{\begingroup\setlength{\jot}{-3pt}\begin{split}}%
{\end{split}\endgroup}
```

But when I try to implement this in the document I get the following error message:

> LaTeX Error: \begin{split} on input line xxx ended by \end{Split}.

I've had success in defining new environments before so I don't know what I'm doing wrong this time.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newenvironment{Split}%
{\begingroup\setlength{\jot}{-3pt}\begin{split}}%
{\end{split}\endgroup}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
y&=x+x\\
&=2x
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{Split}
y&=x+x\\
&=2x
\end{Split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: You don't need the `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` as they are provided by `\newenvironment`. In addition, if you replace `\begin{split}` with `\split` and `\end{split}` with `\endsplit` then your code at least compiles, but the spacing is unaffected. I'm not sure why the spacing is unaffected and I don't have time to investigate now.

Comment: See `texdoc technote` section 6...

Comment: You may simply state `\setlength{\jot}{-3pt}` in the preamble: the length is used in all alignment environments.

Comment: @egreg I explained why I don't want to do that.

Comment: @AndrewSwann OK thanks that explains what's going wrong, I think.  The workarounds mentioned work OK up to a point.  E.g. I can define:
    \def\bsplit#1\esplit{\begingroup\setlength{\jot}{-3pt}\begin{split}#1\end{split}\endgroup}
and that work well if I just have \bsplit ... \esplit.  But it brakes down if you have one embedded in another, e.g. \bsplit \bsplit ... \esplit \esplit - not that I would *need* to do that, except that there are already hundreds of equations in my document and I would like a solution that I can implement via find/replace.

Comment: So you just want that `split` is affected? Not `align` or `gather`?

Comment: @egreg yes that's correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example
\usepackage[vmargin=2cm]{geometry} % just for the example

\doublespacing

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{split}{\linespread{1}\selectfont}{}{}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2]
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
y&=x+x\\
&=2x
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\lipsum*[2]
\begin{align}
y&=x+x\\
&=2x
\end{align}
\lipsum*[2]
\begin{gather}
y=x+x\\
z=2x
\end{gather}
\lipsum*[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can modify the `\gather@split` macro, calling `\linespread{1}\selectfont` before `\spread@equation`.

This won't affect other alignment environments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example
\usepackage[vmargin=2cm]{geometry} % just for the example

\doublespacing

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\gather@split}
  {\spread@equation}
  {\linespread{1}\selectfont\spread@equation}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2]
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
y&=x+x\\
&=2x
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\lipsum*[2]
\begin{align}
y&=x+x\\
&=2x
\end{align}
\lipsum*[2]
\begin{gather}
y=x+x\\
z=2x
\end{gather}
\lipsum*[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]